# Zend framework and PHP Cloud

Tags: zend-framework

I have been playing around with this:
https://my.phpcloud.com/container/create

Unless you have a dev account the link above will not work.

What I am confused about is adding the Zend Framework here.

The choices for a container are:

```
Zend Server 5.6 – PHP 5.3
Zend Server 5.6 – PHP 5.4
Zend Server NextGen Sneak Peek
```

How do I create a empty container with Zend framework configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container is the environment where your files will be hosted. Working projects will be applications inside the container. You can deploy a Zend Framework project to the container, after creating it. It is similar to how we deploy a software in a server.

To create a container with Zend Framework application in it :

1. Create a container with any one of the choices: Zend Server 5.6 – PHP 5.3, Zend Server 5.6 – PHP 5.4, or  Zend Server NextGen Sneak Peek
2. After the container is provisioned, go to your container overview page, which looks like - https://my.phpcloud.com/container/yourcontainername/overview and click "New Application".
3. While creating the new application, you have options to pick a empty Zend Framework application. [See the manual here](http://www.phpcloud.com/help/pg-appman-generic)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with phpcloud but I think you may be confusing Zend Framework and Zend Server. These are two very different things. Zend Framework doesn't really require installation as such, it's just a collection of PHP classes. I would guess that ZF is normally uploaded with the apps that you put on the cloud.